# Is a PC-sync cable universal and allows me to operate a flash of any brand with a PC-sync port from any camera that has a PC sync port?

Tags: off-camera-flash, cables

For example suppose I have a Canon 7D and a Pentax flash AF360FGZ mounted on a hotshoe with a PC sync port. Can I connect that camera and flash to fire in sync? The goal is to shoot self-portraits.

Comment: Any camera *with a PC-sync port*. Many entry level DSLRs no longer include one.

Comment: Well the 7D reffered in the question does. See specifications: http://www.dpreview.com/reviews/canoneos7d/2

Comment: The 7D is referred in the description, but the actual question says *Is a PC-sync cable universal and allows me to operate a flash of any brand from any camera?*

Comment: I will edit the title

Comment: BTW a PC sync port can be added to many cameras via a shoe adapter

Answer (score 2):

Yes, the PC sync is a universal connection, independent of brand.   Manual flash mode only.

Comment: any voltage issues involved? Shall I confidently connect the two without any risk to the camera?

Comment: Not familiar with that one, but isn't the flash only a couple of years old? Surely no voltage issues with a modern flash. This site http://www.botzilla.com/photo/strobeVolts.html indicates several Pentax models are all safe voltage.  You can measure it to be sure, with a volt meter from center pin of foot to the metal foot.  Probably about 5 volts.  7D is modern, safe up to 250 volts.